# No space for pulling docker image with same label in GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

We are using instance group to run docker containers, and set up the instance template to use image as

`us.gcr.io/my-project/my-image:latest`.

When we make any change to the docker image, we label it with `latest` and run:

`gcloud compute instance-groups managed rolling-action restart my-instance-group --region us-central1`.

This was working fine for the initial changes to the image, the instance group vms will pull new images and override previous images. But after more changes were made, it starts to give the error:

`no space left on device`

Essentially, GCP does not handle stale images, it will store the old image copy. But in the case of "rolling update to container-optimized vms", can we get a better automation handling for these use cases? We really don't want to ssh into the host and run `docker image prune -a` every so often manually.

Comment: I think an option to the `rolling-action restart` command to prune old images automatically will be ideal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line at the start of your startup-script [1].

```
docker image prune -a
```

This will remove all unused images before pulling a new image later in your startup-script. Please note, a restart is needed to trigger the startup-script.

Your hard drives will not fill up as a result and your VMs will have the latest docker image running on them.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript

Comment: I think you want `docker image prune -af` in the startup script, which will delete without confirmation.